# Does setting attributed text with attributes on UILabel calls layoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

In my iOS application, I am working with `UILabel`. Just now I observed a very strange behavior of `UILabel`. In `viewDidAppear`, when I am setting attributed text on `UILabel` using only:

```
NSAttributedString(string: "my infinite text. I don't have fixed length.")
```

then `layoutSubviews` is not getting called. But when I am using following method:

```
NSAttributedString(string: "my infinite text. I don't have fixed length.", , attributes: [String : Any]?)
```

`layoutSubviews` of `UILabel` subclass gets called automatically.

Why is it so?

Comment: Auto layouts starts working from `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the view controller lifecycle. when `viewDidLoad` is called, the view hasn't been put into screen yet. The lifecycle method usually goes like this, `viewDidLoad` -> `viewWillAppear` -> `viewWillLayoutSubviews` -> `viewDidLayoutSubviews` -> `viewDidAppear`... this is of course a really simplified version of the explanation though.

Comment: @CoderFrom94 - sorry for my typing mistake. I want to type viewdidAppear. I corrected my question

Comment: Now this is interesting, will check it out

Comment: @CoderFrom94 - please have a look on this